# Store int in 2 chars

Tags: c, casting, char, int

Quick question: Since int is 2 bytes and char is 1 byte, I want to store an int variable in 2 char variables. (like bit 1 - 8 into the first char, bit 9-16 into second char). Using C as programming language.

How can I achieve that? Will something like:

```
int i = 30543;
char c1 = (char) i;
char c2 = (char) (i>>8);
```

do the job?

I couldn't find whether casting an int into a char will just drop the bits 9-16.

Comment: You can't ensure that `int` is two bytes, you can however use `int16_t` from `stdint.h` which is guaranteed to be 2 bytes wide. It's an interesting question but I don't think you can find an answer specific to `char`, but if you think about it, there will be no way to store more than `CHAR_BIT` bits in a `char`, hence the cast is not needed.

Comment: "int is two bytes" raises the question, what compiler are you using? Int is most often 32 bits, so 4 bytes, these days, in both 32 bit and 64 bit environments.

Comment: I'm not sure atm, since it's installed on the university PCs, but my fellow students told me, it's two bytes. Might as well use int16_t though, to be 100% sure, so thanks!

Comment: the posted code will cause a compiler to raise warnings about lost data and/or folding of the data.   suggest adding &0xFF to each of the statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was extracted from the c11 draft n1570

> **6.5.4 Cast operators**
>
> 6. If the value of the expression is represented with greater range or precision than required
>    by the type named by the cast (6.3.1.8), then the cast specifies a conversion even if the
>    type of the expression is the same as the named type and removes any extra range and
>    precision.

So the cast will indeed remove the extra bits, but it's not needed anyway because the value will be implicitly converted to `char`, and the above would apply anyway.

Comment: That's all I needed, so the above should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do:

```
char c1 = (char) ((i << 8) >> 8);

char c2 = (char) (i >> 8);
```